# PHP script lagging my website

Tags: php, mysql, cron

So I have this script (which is important to the website) and it runs every 3-5 minutes.

Basically, what this script does is it gets the information from an API request and update the table with the new API requests.

Problem is, it runs a lot of API requests (about 500?) since my table has 500 entries.

And because of that, my CPU uses throttles to 100% every time this script is ran. So how can I avoid that. How can I limit the CPU usage of this script alone?

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
echo memory_get_usage() . "\n";

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "***", "***", '***');
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM **_streams");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/'.strtolower($row['channel'])), true);
    if ($json_array['stream'] != NULL) {

        // turn them into variables to prevent outside SQL injection
        $displayname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$json_array['stream']['channel']['display_name']);
        $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$json_array['stream']['channel']['status']);
        $game = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$json_array['stream']['channel']['game']);
        $viewers = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$json_array['stream']['viewers']);
        $preview = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$json_array['stream']['preview']['medium']);
        $followers = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$json_array['stream']['channel']['followers']);
        $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());

        mysqli_query($con,"SET NAMES utf8mb4");
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE mybb_streams SET `online` = '1', `title` = '$title', `viewers` = '$viewers', `game` = '$game', `preview` = '$preview', `followers` = '$followers', `lastactive` = '$date' WHERE `channel` = '".strtolower($row['channel'])."'") or die("A MySQL error has occurred.<br />Your Query: UPDATE `streams` SET `online` = `1`, `title` = `$title`, `viewers` = `$viewers`, `game` = `$game`, `preview` = `$preview` WHERE channel = '".strtolower($row['channel'])."'<br /> Error: (" . mysqli_errno($con) . ") " . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    else {
      mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE mybb_streams SET `online` = '0', `viewers` = '0' WHERE `channel` = '".strtolower($row['channel'])."'") or die("A MySQL error has occurred.<br />Your Query: UPDATE streams SET `online` = '0', `viewers` = '0' WHERE `channel` = '".strtolower($row['channel'])."'<br /> Error: (" . mysqli_errno($con) . ") " . mysqli_error($con));
    }

}

echo memory_get_usage() . "\n"; 

?>
```

Database refreshed!

Comment: Don't use deprecated function `mysqli_real_escape_string ` anymore.

Comment: Can you identify which process is using the CPU? I can see nothing here that would max out a multi-core machine, so unless you're running this on an older machine it should be fine. It is possible however that the database is doing something intensive with these update? Maybe a trigger, or you've got a complicated view being updated?

Comment: Well you see, my host said that I keep hitting my CPU limit, not sure why. I know this script is extremely slow, but it is the only way for me to get all the channel info that's stored in my database. Oh and I am using shared hosting at the moment.

Comment: I think you hit the CPU limit because you have more than one cron job executing in the same time. If your script needs 30 minutes to run and you launch it every 5 minutes, then you have 6 scripts running in the same time...

Answer (score 0):

Ya I bet it would be extremely slow. For each stream you A) Make an HTTP request to api.twitch.tv (which php stops all execution until a response is returned from the api) then you execute two queries.

I just looked at the same api and if you do a call to https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams first it will give you a list of all the streams I'm guessing.

So do a single call to get all the streams then loop through the API results and update your database that way.

Comment: Problem is, I want to get the streams that are listed in my database. I have over 500 entries in the database.

Comment: I don't think there is a pretty solution around trying to update all streams at once. You could setup a cron job on your server to slowly update each stream at a specified time. Then you could have a manual function that can manually update a particular stream at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Hope my suggestions will give you little bit help.

My suggestion:
If you are going with CRON Job then you can fix this problem with memory limit

Help Full Links:

1. http://piwik.org/docs/setup-auto-archiving/
2. https://www.urbaninsight.com/2011/06/06/fixing-out-of-memory-problem-for-cron-job
3. https://serverfault.com/questions/295584/php-cli-memory-limit

**Example Code:**

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/cron.php' or
    (isset($_GET['q']) and $_GET['q'] == 'admin/reports/status/run-cron')) {
  ini_set('memory_limit', '256M'); // Set higher value if needed
}
?>
```

My Another Suggestion :

You need to Optimization MySql Innodb Performance.

The best way to improve the performance of SELECT operations is to create indexes on one or more of the columns that are tested in the query. The index entries act like pointers to the table rows, allowing the query to quickly determine which rows match a condition in the WHERE clause, and retrieve the other column values for those rows. All MySQL data types can be indexed.

1. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html
2. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html
3. http://www.sitepoint.com/optimizing-mysql-indexes/
4. http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/04/26/more-on-mysql-transaction-descriptors-optimization/
5. http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/09/20/innodb-performance-optimization-basics-updated/
6. http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/01/innodb-performance-optimization-basics/

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

You can use [nice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_%28Unix%29), does not limit CPU usage but give your script low priority:

```
nice -n 20 php ./streams.php
```

Answer (score 0):

**ReactPHP**

Maybe you could have a look on ReactPHP (https://github.com/reactphp/react) which provides an easy way to use non-blocking requests and promises.

ReactPHP will allow you to send multi requests to your API in the same time without have to wait the end of each.

This page gives you an example of parallel download : https://github.com/reactphp/react/blob/split/examples/parallel-download.php

**MessageQueue**

You also could use a MessageQueue like RabbitMQ (http://www.rabbitmq.com/) to request your API.
Look at this blog which gives an example of migration from a simple request system to RabbitMQ and the pros : http://knplabs.com/blog/2012/02/03/knpbundles-now-uses-rabbitmq/